# Rails: ActionView::Template::Error while removing row from table using designated .js.erb

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I **need a help with removing rows from a table using jQuery** in Rails 4.2. Once I click on the green button, I want to have the entire row deleted and the table refreshed.

As for the logic, I am working with documents and users. A user is able to hide a document and attach a note to specific hiding. Therefore, I've decided to create additional model **Hiding**, which contains references to **User** and **Document** along with other relevant information:

**hiding.rb**

```
class Hiding < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :document
  belongs_to :user
end
```

From the other perspective, **Document** and **User** models have the following association:

```
has_one :hiding
```

After clicking the green button, the controller's *unhide* action gets called:

```
class Admin::HidingsController < AdminController
  authorize_resource

  def index
    @hidings = Hiding.all.page params[:page]
  end

  def unhide
    @hidings = Hiding.all.page params[:page]
    @hiding = Hiding.where(document_id: params[:id])

    # update document and delete hiding from DB 
    search_un_hide_document(false, nil)
  end
end
```

However, when I want to perform deletion of table row via **unhide.js.erb**

```
$('#<%=@hiding.document.id%>').remove()
```

the following exception is triggered:

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `document' for #Hiding::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000000c4508d8>)

I've been stuck on this for some time as I am a newbie in Rails. Could not figure out, how to properly remove those rows without re-rendering entire page again, though.

Your suggestions would be appreciated with big gratitude. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def unhide
   @hidings = Hiding.all.page params[:page]
   @hiding = Hiding.where(document_id: params[:id]).first

   # update document and delete hiding from DB 
   search_un_hide_document(false, nil)
end
```

> Probably you forgot to add .first for @hiding

Edited:

> Instead of where().first, you can also use find_by(document_id:
>   params[:id])

find_by is defined like this

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

Now, 'take' differs from 'first' in regards to order. first returns the first record according to the order of the primary key while take returns whatever the database spits out first.

Comment: Since he only needs one result it should be Hiding.find_by(document_id: params[:id]), but where().first does the same.

Comment: @JollyProgrammer Good recommendation. Updated the answer.